# How to fix two GRUBs due to multiple Linux installations and invalid boot entries

Tags: arch-linux, boot, grub, opensuse

Up until yesterday I was using Arch for the best part of the year, but I decided to try Open Suse Tumbleweed because it seems to be more stable and organized. I installed it using an USB stick and on top of my old Windows installation (I actually erased all Windows partitions using GParted). Now I have two GRUBs installed, and an invalid Windows Boot Manager entry.

I would like the help of someone more experience with GRUB and boot entries to fix this. The output of efibootmgr is the following:

```
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0001,001F,0000,0019,001A,001B,001C,001D,001E,0020,0022,0021,0023,0024
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* GRUB
Boot0002* opensuse-secureboot
Boot0010 Setup
Boot0011 Boot Menu
Boot0012 Diagnostic Splash Screen
Boot0013 Lenovo Diagnostics
Boot0014 Regulatory Information
Boot0015 ThinkShield secure wipe
Boot0016 Startup Interrupt Menu
Boot0017 Rescue and Recovery
Boot0018 MEBx Hot Key
Boot0019* USB CD
Boot001A* USB FDD
Boot001B* NVMe0
Boot001C* NVMe1
Boot001D* ATA HDD0
Boot001E* ATA HDD1
Boot001F* USB HDD
Boot0020* PXE BOOT
Boot0021* HTTPS BOOT
Boot0022* LENOVO CLOUD
Boot0023 Other CD
Boot0024 Other HDD
Boot0025* IDER BOOT CDROM
Boot0026* IDER BOOT Floppy
Boot0027* ATA HDD
Boot0028* ATAPI CD
```

If I boot to opensuse-secureboot, I see the custom GRUB of Tumbleweed with the options to boot to Tumbleweed or Windows. If I boot to GRUB, I see the Arch GRUB with the options to boot to Arch or Windows.

I have a couple of questions (if that's ok):

- How can I just use one GRUB to boot to either Arch or Tumbleweed?
- How to delete the invalid entries?
- How did that happen?
- Is there any difference between my old GRUB and the one that Tumbleweed installed?

Thank you so much in advance! I'm eager to fix this - I went to sleep yesterday with an itch haha.

Comment: Responding to 1. Have you run the `grub-mkconfig` yet?

Comment: I'm a little ignorant when it comes to GRUB. What would grub-mkconfig do to my system?

Comment: `grub-mkconfig` uses `os-prober` to detect all systems and creates a configuration for grub. Considering you're on EFI, if you run `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`, it will update your GRUB config to see all current distros.

Comment: Is there any possibility of this breaking my GRUB?

Comment: It can if you mess up the command ;). If you boot through a recovery USB, you can `cp /boot/grub/grub.cfg /boot/grub/grub.cfg.old`. grub-mkconfig might even do this automatically, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: Running `os-prober` outputs just `/dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi`

Comment: That means that's all `os-prober` sees, which is strange.

Comment: Do you know which partitions you installed your linux on? If so, mount one to /mnt and run os-prober again.

Comment: You also need to remove /EFI/Microsoft from ESP - efi system partition to prevent os-prober from finding Windows entries. And remove UEFI entry 0000 for Windows. https://askubuntu.com/questions/794725/can-i-remove-windows-boot-manager-from-dedicated-ubuntu-computer Generally a major grub update will make it first in grub boot order. So you have to manage grub & updates. I turn off os-prober and add my own entries into 40_custom. With Ubuntu it creates links to boot most current kernel, so I do not even have to edit 40_custom with new kernel.

Comment: @Bobbbay just did that. I mounted my Arch to `/mnt`. It' s luks encrypted, so I had to use `cryptsetup`  first to decrypt it. No luck with `os-prober` - it still outputs the same thing.

Comment: Hey @oldfred, thank you for your reply. Just to make sure I understood you: you are saying that I need to remove the entry Boot0000 from EFI, manually, correct?

Comment: @mrbear ok, let's see one more thing - run `grub-mkconfig -o ~/test.cfg`. This won't mess with your Grub at all, simple spit out a file `test.cfg` that you can send over so. I remember when I had to get rid of windows I just formatted the partition from my recovery USB and went on with installing my distro of choice. EDIT: oh, and Old Fred said remove the boot entry and `rm -rf /boot/EFI/Microsoft`. That might help as well.

Comment: If you do not have Windows, no need for entry in UEFI. Use `sudo efibootmgr -b XXXX -B' as shown in link. Or `man efibootmgr`